# Empty span giving parent weird layout behavior

Tags: html, css

I am making a table-type layout with `div`s and `span`s. I am getting some weird behavior when any of the `span`s are empty - a margin appears at the top of the parent.

I think it might be linked to using `display: inline-block` but I'm not sure why it is doing this.

[Here is what I am talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/qJgab/1/)

Is there any way to fix this strange layout behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to `.ListView_ColParent`

```
.ListView_ColParent {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qJgab/2/)**